# Rails: Specify custom action based on failed activeRecord save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :feed_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

now that I verify that a user cannot subscribe to the same feed twice as per the above code, I would like to specify in a notice that they are already subscribed to the feed. How can I go about specifying a condition if the validation fails, sending a notice other than the generic "Subscribe was unsuccessful"

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
def new
#do things
    if @subscription.save
      redirect_to reader_url, notice: "You are now subscribed to: "+feed.title
    else
      redirect_to reader_url, notice: "Subscribe was unsuccessful!"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was a validation failure, it will populate `@subscription.errors`, which you can inspect and show messages from as needed.

Comment: looks like this is correct, I just need to figure out how to perform conditionals on the .errors enumeration